# C# Regex Match Vs Split for same string

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I was playing around in Linqpad with a regex to extract a string. I have a few doubts that I'm sharing. Can anyone please shed some light on this matter. -

```
string s = "abc|xyz";
Regex.Match(s, @"(\w*)[|]{1}(\w*)").Dump();
Regex.Split(s, @"(\w*)[|]{1}(\w*)").Dump();
```

With `Regex.Match` I get back two groups which I can easily extract.

[image: Regex.Match].

But I don't understand why in `Regex.Split` there are two empty entries.

[image: Regex.Split]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze your string:

```
abc|xyz
\_____/  <-- the match
\_/      <-- capture group 1
    \_/  <-- capture group 2
```

`Regex.Split` includes the captured groups into the resulting array.

The splits happen at the whole match, right there:

```
abc|xyz
\      \
```

So there's an empty string *before* the match, and an empty string *after* the match. The two items in the middle are inserted because of the aforementioned split behavior:

> If capturing parentheses are used in a `Regex.Split` expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array. For example, if you split the string "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within capturing parentheses, the returned array includes a string element that contains the hyphen.

Comment: Is it possible to split by group?

Comment: Why don't you simply split on the `|` char, without using regexes at all?

Comment: You'd either need to shape the whole pattern to fit your needs, or you could loop over matches and groups, and build your list of strings in the loop (basically, reimplement `Split` with the differences you neeed). `Split` is just a convenience function that's really easy to implement yourself.